# Identify PCI device providing network interface

Tags: pci

I can get vendor and device IDs for the device providing a network interface using `/sys/class/net/`:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/p4p2/device/vendor /sys/class/net/p4p2/device/device
0x15b3
0x1013
```

Then I can get `lspci` to show me info about that device:

```
$ lspci -d 0x15b3:0x1013
82:00.0 Infiniband controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27700 Family [ConnectX-4]
82:00.1 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27700 Family [ConnectX-4]
```

So it's dual-port. In this case I happen to know that device `p4p2` is the ethernet side, but is there info in `/sys/class/net/<dev>` which links it to the `82:00.1` entry? Or some other way which doesn't require `sudo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `realpath /sys/class/net/<dev>` or `realpath /sys/class/net/<dev>/device`.

Those should be symbolic links pointing to `/sys/devices/...`, and the target path should include the PCI ID.

If you need just the PCI ID part, try:

```
basename $(realpath /sys/class/net/<dev>/device)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Mellanox HCAs

There is not much information you can dig from `lspci` without `sudo`
Using your pci address: `sudo lspci -s 82:00.0 -vvv` will provide you HCA part number, serial number, PCI bus width and much more

Most of driver related information resides under `/sys/bus/pci/devices/<pci_addr>/infiniband>`

You also can use [**lshca**](https://pypi.org/project/lshca/) utility. It shows you lot's of useful information

Example from [Wiki](https://github.com/MrBr-github/lshca/wiki/Features-overview#System-view):

```
#lshca
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dev #1
 Desc: Mellanox Technologies MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5]
 PN: MCX556A-ECAT  rev. A3
 PSID: MT_0000000008
 SN: MT.............
 FW: 16.28.2006
 Tempr: 45
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  PCI_addr   |  RDMA  | Net  | Numa | IpStat  | Link | Rate | LnkCapWidth | LnkStaWidth | HCA_Type
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000:81:00.0 | mlx5_2 | ib2  |  1   | up_ip4  |  IB  | 100  |   x16 G3    |   x8 >!<    |  MT4119
0000:81:00.1 | mlx5_3 | p2p2 |  1   | up_ip46 | Eth  | 100  |   x16 G3    |   x8 >!<    |  MT4119
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Disclaimer, I'm the `lshca` author